# Is there any way to use one ngModel with more than one inputs in a form?

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel

Please mind that I'm really new to Angular. 
I have a form consists of Year, Make and Model. I am trying to find out a way to bind all these items into one property for generating the name of the object. I can't quite understand why is this not binding the value to the "vehicle.name". What would be the proper way to take care of this?

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" value="{{vehicle.year}}" id="vehcile-info" [(ngModel)]="vehicle.year">
<input class="form-control" type="number" value="{{vehicle.year}}" id="vehcile-info" [(ngModel)]="vehicle.year">
<input class="form-control" type="number" value="{{vehicle.year}}" id="vehcile-info" [(ngModel)]="vehicle.year">


<input class="form-control" type="text" readonly value="{{vehicle.year}} {{vehicle.make}} {{vehicle.model}}" id="vehcile-info" [(ngModel)]="vehicle.name">
```

Vehicle interface:

```
export interface Vehicle {
$key: string;
name: string;
year: string;
make: string;
model: string;
trim?: string;
info?: string;
vin?: string;
}
```

Save Vehicle Function:

```
saveVehicle(vehicle: Vehicle) {
    return this
        .vehicles$
        .push(vehicle)
        .then(_ => console.log('success saving vehicle'))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: you can only bind to the component property

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I understand that rule, but since the form is already generating the value as needed, shouldn't it also bind that value to 'vehicle.name' on submit just like if it was typed?

Comment: i can't see the form or generated value, so I can tell you what you typed is absolutely has non sense.

Comment: I can't seem to understand your given code. Please post entire code of the component?

Comment: Here's the plunk for the entire component:
http://plnkr.co/edit/eDLUeeX4En5Dn8I4XJzd

Comment: You are using vehicle in template. But I can't find it in component.

Comment: @RomanC what I meant by generated is that the value of the input field that I want to bind is being pulled from the other fields. 
So if I fill the fields: "year", "make" and "model", I'm seeing the name is already being populated in the "name" field. I just can't happen bind the field value to the "vehicle.name" property. 
I think I'm trying to do something nonsense as you said, this probably needs to be handled in the function. 
Thanks for sparing time.

Comment: @SKG I'm using the vehicle in the service and using the service in the component. When I update the fields by typing I can push the values just fine but when I update the field value using other fields' values I can't seem to bind it. I may be onto something that's not really reasonable here... "vehicle" on the template is just an async as value of Vehicles$ list.

Comment: @ReturnTable First you have to write a function, then create an Observable with this value when subscribed return a handler. Then set a value to the field. That's all. I believe I did it previously and received invaluable absent.

Comment: @RomanC Thank you, that's what I was afraid of. I'll also try to edit the save function first to join properties into one string to create "name" property and then push, maybe I can get it to work that way, too.

Comment: @ReturnTable you are probably on the wrong way because what you trying to do doesn't work.